# Specify "production version" without Web Hosting

Tags: facebook

When I open my **Instant Games** app I get *Your instant game doesn't have a production version* error.

How can I specify such *production version* **without** Web Hosting (thus uploading a .zip archive)?

Comment: Sounds as if you might just need to switch your app from dev to live mode?

Comment: @misorude App was **in Development** mode and only I could play it (**page does not exist** was displayed to other accounts). I switched to **in development** and now everyone see **Production version was not specified** error :( . But I can't find where I can specify production URL for a version you do **not** host on Facebook.

Comment: _“or a version you do **not** host on Facebook”_ - first you said you uploaded it via zip to Facebook, now you are asking about the opposite thing …? Now which one is it?

Comment: Instant Games are always hosted by Facebook. It sounds like you simply neglected to perform the necessary steps as they are outlined under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/instant-games/test-publish-share#testing, specifically the “Productionize the Build” step.

Comment: @misorude Okey, I guess I mixed up **Instant games** with **Web hosting** where [it says](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/contenthosting/) you can choose Hosting Type and **Instant Games Application Hosting** option currently set to *false* in my project also confused me ;)

Comment: @misorude could you please post your last comment so I can accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instant Games are always hosted by Facebook.

It sounds like you simply missed to perform the necessary steps as they are outlined under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/instant-games/test-publish-share#testing, specifically the “Productionize the Build” step:

> To test the upload in a production environment, the build must first be staged for production. Click the "★" button to push the build to production.

Comment: So that **Instant Games Application Hosting** option has no relevance.

Comment: Web Games (what used to be known as Canvas platform) can be hosted on your own server, or via Facebook hosting. For Instant Games however, hosting them yourself was never an option AFAIK, with those you always have to upload a zip file to Facebook.